# Help proving a logarithmic inequality

Tags: real-analysis, logarithms

So this inequality $\ln(1+\frac{1}{\ln(n)}) \leq \frac{1}{\ln(n+1)}$ appeared in a proof I was reading, and it isn't clear to me how to prove it. I plotted it and it seems to hold.

[image: Plot of the 2 functions]

If anyone has any hints on how to prove this, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does the $log$ means $ln$ which means $log_e$ or $log_{10}$?

Comment: @ranjit doesn't matter.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to clarify. I mean natural logarithm, with base e.

Comment: @Holly Morph, then edit the question.

Comment: It does not hold for $1<n\le1.89999$.

Comment: @player3236 Interesting.  I wonder if there is the missing constraint that $n$ is a positive integer $\geq 2$?

Comment: Here's a [plot of the two functions](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJwryMkv0YjOyU_XMNQ21AfRFZqaOgpQprahZqyOgoahnqmOgommDpdCTmp6al5KfE5iUmqOrUaRukoMTGsMVK-Kuo4CUBwmADRBRR2kM70oMyUnMy-12FYpNzErv0hJEwBoFSLb&lang=sage), using Sage. I expect that [Bernoulli's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli's_inequality) may be relevant.

Comment: Both functions are decreasing and you can numerically evaluate their difference at $n=1.5$ and $n=2.5$ to conclude via IVT that from somewhere in the interval $[1.5, 2.5]$, onwards, the inequality holds and you're done. Unless, of course, you're interested in finding the intersection point of the graphs.

Comment: You might try writing the logs as integrals and try to bound the resulting double integral by an upper sum less than 1. You only need to find the right partition, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume that $n$ is an integer greater than $1,$ and treat
separately the cases $n = 2,$ $n = 3,$ and $n \geqslant 4.$

### $n = 2$:

\begin{gather*}
\ln3 = \ln\frac{1+\tfrac12}{1-\tfrac12} =
1 + \frac{(\tfrac12)^2}{3} + \frac{(\tfrac12)^4}{5} + \cdots
< 1 + \frac1{12(1 - \tfrac14)} = \frac{10}9, \\
\therefore\ \exp\left(\frac1{\ln3}\right) >
\exp\left(\frac9{10}\right) >
1 + \frac9{10} + \frac{81}{200} + \frac{9\cdot4}{6\cdot10\cdot5}
+\frac{4^2}{24\cdot5^2} \\
= \frac{1471}{600} > \frac{1470}{600} = 2 + \frac9{20}; \\
\ln2 = \ln\frac{1+\tfrac13}{1-\tfrac13} >
\frac23 + \frac2{3^4} = \frac{56}{81}, \\
\therefore\ 1 + \frac1{\ln2} < \frac{137}{56}
= 2 + \frac{25}{56} < 2 + \frac9{20}
< \exp\left(\frac1{\ln3}\right), \\
\therefore\ \ln\left(1 + \frac1{\ln2}\right) < \frac1{\ln3}.
\end{gather*}

### $n = 3$:

\begin{gather*}
2\cdot12^2 = 288 < 289 = 17^2,
\ \therefore \sqrt2 < \frac{17}{12}; \\
\exp\left(\frac1{2\sqrt2}\right) > 1 + \frac1{2\sqrt2} + \frac1{16}
= \frac{17}{16} + \frac{\sqrt2}4 > \sqrt2, \\
\therefore\ \exp\left({\frac1{\sqrt2}}\right) > 2,
\ \therefore\ \ln2 < \frac1{\sqrt2},
\ \therefore\ (\ln2)^2 < \frac12; \\
\ln3 > 1, \ \therefore\ \ln\left(1 + \frac1{\ln3}\right) < \ln2
< \frac1{2\ln2} = \frac1{\ln4}.
\end{gather*}

### $n \geqslant 4$:

\begin{gather*}
\ln2 = \ln\frac{1+\tfrac13}{1-\tfrac13} > \frac23,
\ \therefore\ \ln n \geqslant \ln4 > \frac43; \\
\frac1{\ln n} < 1,
\ \therefore\ \ln\left(1 + \frac1{\ln n}\right) <
\frac1{\ln n} - \frac1{2(\ln n)^2} + \frac1{3(\ln n)^3}, \\
\therefore\ \frac1{\ln(n + 1)} - \ln\left(1 + \frac1{\ln n}\right)
> \frac1{2(\ln n)^2} - \frac1{3(\ln n)^3}
- \frac{\ln\left(1 + \tfrac1n\right)}{(\ln n)\ln(n + 1)} \\
> \frac1{2(\ln n)^2} - \frac1{4(\ln n)^2} - \frac1{n(\ln n)^2}
\geqslant 0.
\end{gather*}